# How do I access higher level variables/objects in a child object?

Tags: c#, function, oop, xna

Something I haven't ever figured out how to do in C# is the following:

Say I have two classes: Game.cs, and Player.cs.

I find that anything that belongs to Game.cs must be passed on through the arguments of any function that belongs to Player.cs. For example, if I had a sound effect loaded in Game, and Player was a child of Game, and Player has a function "PlaySoundEffect()", the only way that Player could access that sound is if I pass it through the arguments: "PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffect sound)"

What I want to know is this:

1. How can I access the object(s) without including them as an argument?
2. Why can't I access them like so: "Game.sound", even though sound is in Game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make any global variables in your Game class `static` - meaning, they aren't part of the Game instance, and instead are globally accessible.

EG, in Game.cs
`SoundEffect sound;`
becomes
`static SoundEffect sound;`

Now your player class can just do
`Game.sound.Play();`
or whatever it needs.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I needed to make the SoundEffect a public static.

Answer (score 0):

`sound` is a property of any specific **instance** of `Game`.

You can only get it from a specific instance.

Instead, you can add a `Game` instance as a property of `Player`, so that each player has a reference to its game.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure at the moment how XNA handles the main Game class, but I don't think it's static, and I don't know if the Game is an instance or not. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: @user2593449: I've never used XNA, but static and instance are opposites.  Either it's a static class, and all of its members are static, and your code would work, or it's a regular class with at least instance.  The latter is much more likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access them because they aren't *static*.

But,

You could wrap them, and pass them to the player. Something like this:

```
class GameSoundManager {
    public SoundEffect PlayerDie { get; set; }
}

class Game {
    private GameSoundManager _soundManager;
    private Player _player;

    public Game() {
        _soundManager = new GameSoundManager() {
            PlayerDie = // load the sound
        };

        _player = new Player(_soundManager);
    }
}

class Player {
    private GameSoundManager _soundManager;

    public Player(GameSoundManager soundManager) {
        _soundManager = soundManager;
    }

    // use _soundManager.PlayerDie anywhere in your player class.
}
```